# How can I modify the miniature image of backoffice product?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Actually the miniature image is from thumbnail field, but I want to modify this widget and set other image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the OOTB definition of base context -> preview urlQualifier. Here is my example, I change the default of the mini image to get from the picture field instead of the thumbnail.

```
    <context merge-by="type" parent="GenericItem" type="Product" component="base">
    <y:base>
        .........
        <y:preview urlQualifier="picture?:thumbnail"/>
    </y:base>
</context>
```